# Using setData in HighCharts multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In my example http://jsfiddle.net/uwdz8rm8/, I'm only able to get setData to run once. I would like to switch between two data sets. Any ideas?

The jQuery I have is proven working in my test div but not on Highcharts

```
$('input:radio[name=penetrationoptions]').change(function () {
    var chart = $('#KPI_Penetration_Chart').highcharts();
    if (this.value == 'amount') {
        chart.series[0].setData(amountData);
        $('#testing').css("background", "red");
    } else if (this.value == 'count') {
        chart.series[0].setData(countData);
        $('#testing').css("background", "green");
    }
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $('#KPI_Penetration_Chart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'pie'
        },

        series: [{
            data: $.extend(true,[],amountData)
        }]
    });
```

All I changed is to copy `amountData` the first time.  You'll discover that both variables end up pointing to the same data set if you don't.

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/uwdz8rm8/3/

Comment: Wow thanks so much, can you tell me how this made it work, and why would both variables point to the same data? This will really help me learn. Also, anyway to refactor this to become less redundant?

Comment: I think it's happening in Highcharts - both variables end up as references to the same object.

Comment: Interesting, so how does .extend fix this?